# Why area under a curve equals the sum of values of function/quantities taken elementally?

Tags: differentiation, integration, mathematics, calculus

**Background:**

I was taught basic formulas of differentiation and integration when I started learning physics. However, it wasn't taught through intuitions and concepts. It was like : " Hey these are some common formulas. Learn them. We'll use them in physics for derivations."

As said, it was used for deriving things. I would like to give a specific example which was very commonly done while learning physics to illustrate my question :

" Consider a rod of length d$x$. The electric field due to this is d$E$. To get net field due to rod, we will add all field elements due to individual d$x$."

The electric field here was just an example. This method is very common like calculating moment of inertia($I$), distance travelled $(S)$, magnetic field per biot-savart law(d$B$), etc.

However, now after almost an year after that, I learnt that the integral of a function is the area under the curve of that function.(Assuming function as always positive like physical quantities are usually positive.)

Hence, I posed this problem. **Why does adding elemental values of a function to get net(or say collective)  value is same as calculating area of that function under the given variable?**

Can you make it easier for me to understand that how the mathematical perspective (the area of the function $y=1$ with respect to variable electric field) is related to physics perspective ( The field of a system due to addition of field of it's small components)

Moreover, I have also got to know that things like elemental quantities like  electric field due to small component d$E$ is meaningless. Because d$E$ is not a number/value.

Comment: What is an "elemental value"? The $ \mathrm{d}E$s we're "adding" here are *infinitesimals*, not "elementals".

Comment: @ACuriousMind Yeah I meant that only.

Comment: Have you seen the [Riemann definition of the integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) yet? Basically, take a bunch of points in the domain of the function (positions $\vec{x}$ for the electric field, say). Calculate the function's value $\vec{E}(\vec{x})$ at those points, and multiply these values by the distance ($\Delta x$) between each of your points. This gives a rough approximation of the area under the curve. Taking the limit as the number of points goes to infinity and $\Delta x$ goes to zero, you recover the true area (the integral), the sum of all the $\vec{E}(\vec{x})dx$.

Comment: Perhaps any course in real analysis would help.

Comment: @JaredPopowski Yes. But I looked up this just now . Fortunately this is the integral that I've learnt in my math class.